# Failing to send via ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have searched around but I can't find what is going wrong with my script. I am expecting to see the content posted both to the MySQL database and into my `div` `.PostedList`, however when I submit I get nothing, the page content does not change at all (the callback does not seem to be executed).

### JavaScript/jQuery

```js
$(function () {
    $(".button").click(function () {

        var one = $("#one").val();
        var two = $("#two").val();
        var three = $("#three").val();

        var content = 'one' + 'two' + 'three';

        if (content == '') {
            alert("Fields Missing");
        } else {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.php",
                data: content,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {

                    $(content).hide().prependTo('.PostedList').fadeIn("fast");

                    document.getElementById('one', 'two', 'three').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('name', 'two', 'three').focus();

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

### HTML

```html
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="one"><br />
<textarea type="text" id="two"/></textarea><br />
<input type="radio" id="three" value="white" />
<input type="radio" id="three" value="black" />
<p> <input class="button" type="submit" value="Post" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: What is the error? What are you expecting to see, and what is it that you're seeing instead?

Comment: Flagged as minimal understanding of the problem: *Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also:* [**Stack Overflow question checklist**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I am expecting to see the content be posted both to the mysql database and into my div `PostedList` however when I submit I get nothing, not even a page refresh.

Comment: @User_coder why should the page refresh? There was no form submission, just a behind the scene AJAX call.

Comment: @User_coder See, that wasn't hard. Now you could edit your question to include such information, thus helping us to solve your problem.
**Note:** You should not get a page refresh with an AJAX call.

Comment: @JeffNoel my english is not so good so I apologise. By refresh I mean nothing is being sent. I really enjoy stackoverflow so please don't downvote me so I get banned. I am a learning developer. I am sorry for bad english.

Comment: It's okay, @InGodITrust and I were just confused by the term you used. I'll fix that up for you.

Comment: Well, Have you checked the firebug console to see if there is a request getting sent to the said URL?

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById` only takes **one** ID value, not several like a jQuery selector

Swap

```
document.getElementById('one', 'two', 'three').value = '';
document.getElementById('name', 'two', 'three').focus();
```

for

```
$('#one', '#two', '#three').val('');
$('#choose_one_id').focus(); // Only one field can have focus at a time!
```

Addtionally, You probably want to change

```
var content = 'one' + 'two' + 'three';
```

to

```
var content = one + two + three;
```

Comment: Made those changes yet still nothing, the content does not prependTo the div  `.PostedList` any other suggestions? or a good example of an alternative way to achieve this?